# Get the last deactivated worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vba6

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Msgbox(worksheet.Name)
End Sub
```

How can I get the last deactivated Sheet once I press on any sheet other than the sheet of interest.

Answer (score 3):

1. You firstly create a `Public` variable on top of `ThisWorkbook` code module (in the declarations area):

```
Public lastSheetName As String
```

2. Put the next code in the `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` event (also in `ThisWorkbook` code module):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
   lastSheetName = Sh.name
End Sub
```

3. Then you can return the name of the last deactivated sheet with a simple `Sub` or inside another event code. Try pasting the next code in a standard module and run it. Of course, after you deactivated at least a sheet...

```
Sub LastDeactivatedSheet()
   MsgBox ThisWorkbook.lastSheetName
End Sub
```

3.a Or put the same code in the `Workbook_SheetActivate` event , in this way:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
   MsgBox "You are coming from " & ThisWorkbook.lastSheetName
End Sub
```

Each time you activate another sheet, it will inform you from which sheet you come...

Comment: @Manideep Karthik: Didn't the above solution solve your problem? Did you find some time to test it?